# Page Redirect but show section of target page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is this possible without JS?

I have a menu item which links to a to a section of the home page.

```
<a class="menu-item-link one-page-nav-item" href="#payments">Payment Options</a>
```

Of course this works only for the page where the `id` is present in the DOM. Can I change the link so that it will work from another page without JS on the target page for scrolling. That is the link opens new page and scrolls to the section.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
<a class="menu-item-link one-page-nav-item" href="http://myurl.com#payments">Payment Options</a>
```

All examples I am finding refer to linking to a page section on the current page.

Thanks!

Comment: What you tried should work, providing that the **myurl.com** page has an element with `#payments` id.

Comment: `http://myurl.com#payments` should work just fine, assuming the element exists on that page, for instance like this -> https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#complete-example

Comment: Guys, thanks! I had typo at this end! Works perfect